# Decrypted token doesn't contain anything after decryption, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cryptography

As the title says after i decrypt my encrypted information and turn that into a string it contains nothing. If I print it to the console before turning it into a string it simply shows "b' '" which i believe is used in turning bytes into strings, but i have no idea why it's there. But if it's printed to the console after it's been turned into a string it'll print nothing.

```
import tkinter
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

class Cryptography:

    def encrypt(self, string):
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        self.f = Fernet(key)
        byteString = str.encode(string)
        self.token = self.f.encrypt(byteString)
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, self.token.decode() + "\n")
        w.pack()

    def decrypt(self):
        global token
        try:
            decrypted = self.f.decrypt(self.token)
        except (NameError, AttributeError):
            w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, "you didn't yet encrypt anything\n")
            w.pack()
        decrypted = self.f.decrypt(self.token)
        print(decrypted)
        dsAsString = decrypted.decode("utf-8")
        print("/n" + dsAsString)
        w.insert(tkinter.INSERT, dsAsString + "\n")
        w.pack()
```

Comment: Is your question about how to get the token to _display_, or are you asking why your token isn't being computed properly? It sounds like the latter, in which case you should remove the tkinter tag, and remove the tkinter code from the example.

Comment: **Works for me!** - *"print it to the console"*: This is not shown in your Questions code!

Comment: @stovfl I put the printing in to the code. If you test it now it should print "b' '" in the console if encrypt and decrypt a string. Should i add the code from my entire project so that people can see the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley The question is indeed about why token loses its information during encrypting and decrypting. I left the tkinter in, because that was my code and there's a possibility that it could be a problem, since i don't know the source of the problem. Everything seems to have been done correctly. Should i add my entire code so people can see the problem easier?

Comment: No, we don't want your entire code. Instead, remove the tkinter code and replace it with static strings and print statements to see if the problem persists. If the problem goes away, then it means you're making false assumptions about what the tkinter code is doing. If the problem remains, you've just ruled out tkinter as a source of the problem.

Comment: @MiikaVuorio: *"now it should print "b' '""*: **No, works for me too**. You hava a *blank* in your `b' '`, check if you pass **only** a blank to `.encrypt(" ")`.

Comment: It works for me too.  However you called `self.f.decrypt(self.token)` twice in `decrypt` function.  Also better check whether `string` parameter to `encrypt` function is not empty.

Comment: I'll throw the entire code here since people are saying it's working so maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I just found the problem. Basically i was using tkinter.Entry() and wanted to use what was written in there as the text to be what was to be encrypted. As such i ran the .get() for the entry field, but that was outside of the function so it would assign string to be e.get() when there was nothing in the entry field since it was loaded while everything else was loaded. So yes. The problem was outside of the code shown in the question and as such it worked for others, but not me. TL;DR the string variable was empty.